# Flash/Actionscript3 - Interactive Chart

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder, flash-cs5

i need to build a chart, an interactive one, ex:

There's a chart with a range of values, and the user can control that range turning it smaller or larger (in order to see more or less values/data).

My concern is where can i find a class, or 3rd party component that i can use to buil an interactive simple, intuitive chart with use (if possible) of AS3?

Comment: maybe flyCharts 2.0 could help? isn't it free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of AS3 Libraries for creating charts that you can use. [Here is a link](http://sixrevisions.com/flashactionscript/10-useful-flash-components-for-graphing-data/) to some of your options. Also, if you are authoring in Flash Builder using Flex, you may have access to a large number of charting components through that framework's library.